# Как ЕЖЕДНЕВНО использовать firefox дополнения без загрузки в магазин?

Tags: javascript, firefox, chrome-extension, расширения

Я делаю расширение и не хочу показывать его миру, пока не доделаю, поэтому не хочу загружать на addons.mozilla.org. Но некоторое время мне нужно его использовать ежедневно, а для этого как я понял, оно должно быть подписано, либо загружено как временное, но тогда оно будет работать только до перезапуска браузера, что мне не подходит.

Есть ли способ подключения дополнения для постоянного использования, без публикации в магазине расширений firefox на время разработки??

Например в chrome можно один раз указать на каталог расширения и использовать его после перезагрузки браузера.

Comment: а сделать его приватным в магазине разве нельзя?

Comment: @ThisMan не знаю, сейчас проверю. Но в любом случае - это подразумевает выгрузку кода, значит сотрудник mozilla (например модератор) будет иметь доступ к недоделанному плагину. А ещё, скорее всего, придётся каждое обновление загружать таким способом, что добавляет лишние шаги для тестирования

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой и нашёл вот такую [статью на форуме](https://forum.mozilla-russia.org/viewtopic.php?id=70326).

Но в таком случае отладкой расширения нельзя заниматься, плюс возможны проблемы с установкой новых расширений из AMO и обновлением имеющихся.

Поэтому, стоит сделать копию файлов FF.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).